# Spring Boot - Flatten JSON Entity returned by JPA specification for exporting to excel

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson-databind

I am creating a Spring Boot project for inventory management. I have an Entity called InwardInventory that has one to many relationship with another entity called InwardOutwardList. I am using JPA Specification to filter the Entity InwardInventory and it is working fine. Response I receive after filter is

```
{
    "inwardInventory": {
        "content": [
            {
                
                "inwardid": 19497,
                "date": "2019-05-28",
                "vehicleNo": "TRUCK",
                "supplierSlipNo": "",
                "ourSlipNo": "",
                "inwardOutwardList": [
                    {
                        "entryid": 19499,
                        "product": {
                            "productName": "Cement",
                          },
                        "quantity": 100.0
                    },
                    {
                        "entryid": 19500,
                        "product": {
                            "productName": "Iron",
                          },
                        "quantity": 30.0
                    }
                ],
                "warehouse": {
                    "warehouseName": "war2"
                },
                "supplier": {
                    "name": "Bright Traders"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to export this data to excel. So, I need to flatten this response to something like this.

```
{
    "inwardInventory": {
        "content": [
            {
                
                "inwardid": 19497,
                "date": "2019-05-28",
                "vehicleNo": "TRUCK",
                "supplierSlipNo": "",
                "ourSlipNo": "",
                "entryid": 19499,
                "productName": "Cement",
                "quantity": 100.0,
                "warehouseName": "war2",
                "name": "Bright Traders"
            },
            {
                
                "inwardid": 19497,
                "date": "2019-05-28",
                "vehicleNo": "TRUCK",
                "supplierSlipNo": "",
                "ourSlipNo": "",
                "entryid": 19500,
                "productName": "Iron",
                "quantity": 30.0,
                "warehouseName": "war2",
                "name": "Bright Traders"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I know that I can do this by iterating over each inward inventory and then nested iteration over each product and creating custom DAO. However, that doesn't seem to be optimised solution.

I also cannot use projections or native queries with custom select columns because they cannot be integrated with jpa specification. Can someone suggest me best approach that can be used to achieve this in most optimal way.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you consider pojo mapping using any framework like MapStruct? Instead of changing your persistence layer, the transformation work is best suited in your business layer using mapping tools. Take a look at [Controlling nested bean mappings](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#controlling-nested-bean-mappings) from MapStruct which can accomplish same thing. Having said that, introducing MapStruct ONLY for this one use case may be overkill.

Comment: @Avnish I checked MapStruct. I understand that it can be used to map entity to DTO fields. But I will still need to iterate over each element returned from repository and then call mapper method and add it to another list of dto. I want to avoid that iteration. It may consume lot of time iterating over thousands of records. You know of any other concept that can help?

Comment: Actually MapStruct can take care of collections all by itself, look at [Mapping collections](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-collections) for further details. If, however, your concern is with regard to time complexity due to huge number of objects that you have bigger problem IMHO at persistence layer. In that case, I'll strongly suggest to use Stream instead of any Collection in your repository and use Mapper as part of the stream processing in your business layer to flatten the objects.

Comment: Use @JsonUnwrapped then using ObjectMapper make data as json then  map as your dto class the json

Comment: @Eklavya I alreadt tried unwrapping. Unwrapping works good in case of nested entity. but in my case, I have list of nested entity. So, it is not helping. JsonUnwrapped flatens only one level of  nested entity. So, I still receive a list if inwardOutwardList in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled this through custom serializer. Sample code below

```
@Component
public class OutwardExportSerializer extends StdSerializer<OutwardInventoryExportDAO> 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected OutwardExportSerializer(Class<OutwardInventoryExportDAO> t) 
    {
        super(t);
    }
    protected OutwardExportSerializer() 
    {
        this(null);
    }
    @Override
    public void serialize(OutwardInventoryExportDAO value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException 
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        for(InwardOutwardList ioList:value.getInwardOutwardList())
        {
            System.out.println("Serialization starts for OutWardID"+value.getOutwardid());
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeNumberField("outwardid", value.getOutwardid());
            gen.writeStringField("date",df.format(value.getDate()));
            gen.writeStringField("purpose",value.getPurpose()!=null?value.getPurpose():"");
            gen.writeStringField("slipNo",value.getSlipNo()!=null?value.getSlipNo():"");
            gen.writeStringField("product",ioList.getProduct().getProductName()!=null?ioList.getProduct().getProductName():"");
            gen.writeStringField("measurement unit",ioList.getProduct().getMeasurementUnit()!=null?ioList.getProduct().getMeasurementUnit():"");
            gen.writeNumberField("quantity",ioList.getQuantity()!=null?ioList.getQuantity():0.0);
            gen.writeNumberField("closing stock",ioList.getClosingStock()!=null?ioList.getClosingStock():0.0);
            gen.writeStringField("warehouse",value.getWarehouse()!=null?value.getWarehouse():"");
            gen.writeStringField("contractor",value.getContractor()!=null?value.getContractor():"");
            gen.writeStringField("additionalInfo",value.getAdditionalInfo()!=null?value.getAdditionalInfo():"");
            gen.writeStringField("usageLocation",value.getUsageLocation()!=null?value.getUsageLocation():"");
            gen.writeStringField("usageArea",value.getUsageArea()!=null?value.getUsageArea():"");
            gen.writeEndObject();
            System.out.println("Serialization ends for OutWardID"+value.getOutwardid());
        }
        
    }
}
```